# Extracting the last three characters of a words and searching to find matches for the last three characters

Tags: c++, search, vector

i have a vector named words `vector<string>words` which contains multiple words. i need to funtion to get the last three characters of the word and be able to search those last three characters and find words that have the same ending. for example if a user enters the word time i need to return lime, slime, dime, etc...

the code i have typed word when i put the ending manually to be searched for example

```
copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(), back_inserter(logy), [](const string& get1) { return get1.find("logy") != string::npos; });
for (const string& s : logy) cout << "  " << s << '\n';
```

it returned

```
idealogy
logy
etc...
```

but when i put it into a function and change the constant value to a variable it doesnt compile.

```
void Files::rhymes()
{
    string get;
    cout << "Please Enter word to find rhymming words: ";
    cin >> get;
//need something here to get the last three letters for the word

    
    copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(), back_inserter(logy), [](const string& get1) { return get1.find(get) != string::npos; });//looks for words with last three letters from get in them
    for (const string& s : logy) cout << "  " << s << '\n';

}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler error message to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the capture : `[&get](const string& get1)` so the variable `get` is visible inside the lambda.

```
int main()
{ 
    using namespace std;
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::vector<std::string> logy;

    string get;
    cout << "Please Enter word to find rhymming words: ";
    cin >> get;
   
    //looks for words with last three letters from get in them
    copy_if(words.begin(),
            words.end(),
            back_inserter(logy),
            [&get](const string& get1){ 
                return get1.find(get) != string::npos; 
            });

    for (const string& s : logy) cout << "  " << s << '\n';

}
```

Edit : as requested :

```
auto finishWith = [](const std::string& last3, const std::string& word)
{
    if ( word.size() < last3.size() ) return false;
    return std::string(word.end() -  last3.size(), word.end()) == last3;

};

copy_if(words.begin(),
        words.end(),
        back_inserter(logy),
        [&finishWith,&get](const string& get1){ 
            return finishWith(get,get1); 
        });
```

You can also use [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Comment: thanks can i also know how to get the last three letters of a word

Comment: Edited, if it answers the question, don't forget to flag as resolved